# UDK : Problem with Touching Actors

Tags: udk, unreal

In my game I am trying to see all touching actors of a particular DynamicSMActor and it does return only two Actors as touching Actors - Water Volume and Player Pawn. It is ignoring all the other DynamicSMActors that are touching. I actually tried different values for collision type, Blocking type, etc,. No success.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by touching?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the objects are actually touching (colliding) and not just passing through. You can do this by logging the touch and untouch events in unrealscript or via kismet. If they are passing through without touch firing, the collision properties of one or more of the actors needs adjusted accordingly to allow collision with each other.

In unrealscript, Actor:

- event Touch( Actor Other, PrimitiveComponent OtherComp, vector HitLocation, vector HitNormal );
- event PostTouch( Actor Other ); // called for PendingTouch actor after physics completes
- event UnTouch( Actor Other );

In kismet, new event -> physics -> touch.